# Excel - Times a month and day occur between 2 dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an Excel sheet where someone types in the date for a yearly bill.  I need to know how many times we need to pay that bill between 2 dates.

For example if a bill is due every year on May 31st, the user will type in 5/31/2014.  I need to know how many time we will pay that bill between 5/15/2014 and 5/15/2018.  (The between dates will change).  I can't just take the number of years between the start and end dates because in the example above the start and end dates could be 6/1/2014 and 5/30/2018, in which case I only have to pay the bill in 2015, 2016, and 2017, which makes 3 times.

I have this formula which calculates the number of times a certain day occurs between 2 dates: `SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT($Q$2&":"&$R$2)))=F4))`(Q2 is the begin date, R2 is the end date, and F4 has the day of the month)  But I can't figure out how to get this to work for a month and day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the specific date in G4 you can use this version

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($Q$2&":"&$R$2)),"ddmmm")=TEXT(G4,"ddmmm")))`

Comment: Works exactly like I wanted.  I knew that formula was close.  Thank you for seeing what I couldn't figure out.